# Cannot access nested data from action creator which grabs data from contentful

Tags: reactjs, redux, state

So i am trying to access state from a component via react-redux's connect. The state is coming from an asynchronous action grabbing data from the Contentful api. I am pretty sure its because i am replacing the article:{} in the state with article: action.article (this action.article has nested data).

Here is the component:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactMarkDown from 'react-markdown';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getArticle } from '../../actions/blog.actions';

class ArticlePage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getArticle(this.props.match.params.id)
    }
    render() {
        let {article} = this.props;
        return (
            <div className='article-page-wrapper'>
                <div className='navbar-background'></div>
                <div className='article-details'>
                    <img src={`https:${article}`} />
                </div>
                <ReactMarkDown className={'main-content'} source={article.blogContent} />
                {console.log(this.props.article)}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        article: state.blogReducer.article
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        getArticle: (articleId) => {
            dispatch(getArticle(articleId));
        }
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ArticlePage);
```

Here is the action:

```js
export function getArticle (articleId) {
    return function (dispatch) {
        dispatch(getArticleRequest())
        client.getEntries({'sys.id':`${articleId}`,include:1})
            .then((article) =>{
                console.log(article)
                dispatch(getArticleSuccess(article.items[0].fields));
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                dispatch(getArticleError(error));
            })
    }
}

export function getArticleRequest () {
    return {
        type: types.GET_ARTICLE_REQUEST
    }
}

export function getArticleSuccess (article) {
    return {
        type: types.GET_ARTICLE_SUCCESS,
        article: article
    }
}

export function getArticleError (error) {
    return {
        type: types.GET_ARTICLE_ERROR,
        error: error
    }
}
```

Here is the reducer:

```js
import * as types from '../types/blog.types'; 

const initialState = {
    articles:[],
    article:[],
    error: null,
    loading: true
}

export default function blogReducer (state=initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case types.GET_ALL_ARTICLES_REQUEST :
        return {...state, loading: true}

        case types.GET_ALL_ARTICLES_SUCCESS :
        return {...state,loading:false, articles:action.articles.items}    
        
        case types.GET_ALL_ARTICLES_ERROR :
        return {...state, loading:false, error: action.error}

        case types.GET_ARTICLE_REQUEST :
        return {...state, loading: true}

        case types.GET_ARTICLE_SUCCESS :
        return {...state,loading:false,article: action.article}
        
        case types.GET_ARTICLE_ERROR :
        return {...state, loading:false, error: action.error}

        default :
        return state
        }
}
```

Here is the structure of the data being retrieved from Contentful:
[image]

So it fails in the ArticlePage when i try and do article.authorImage.fields in the src for the authors image on the article. Here is the error message:

[image]

I am pretty sure its because when the empty {} in the state is updated by replacing it with the nested data from getArticle, it isn't setting the newState to the entire payload.

I would appreciate any help you can give, if it is indeed due to nested state and mutations can you provide a way of setting the state to equal the payload of the action.

Comment: Add a conditional check for undefined before using data, since you are dispatching an async action

Comment: So i just realised that i am performing two async actions first of all searching by id of article then link resolution of the image assets within the article payload. So I tried this.props.article ? but what i actually needed to do was this.props.article.authorImage. Thanks for the quick response, if you turn yours into an answer ill tick it as correct

Answer (score 1):

When setting article in your redux store, you are setting

```
article: article.items[0].fields
```

whereas you are trying to access fields from `this.props.article.fields`, instead you have a fields called authorImage under fields which in turn contains fields key, so either you must use

```
this.props.articles.authorImage.fields
```

Also check for `undefined` property before using it since it may not be present initially and will only be populated on an async Request

Comment: so each asset (the main article and the img within the article, have a fields property (which describes the various pieces of content). This is why you see it in the action and in the component. The check for undefined worked..

Comment: @Shubham said that right, you already have fields object as article in your component, you need to decide what you want to pass to your component. 

One more thing worth noting is, that you initialized article as array in your reducer, whereas you modified it to javascript object when getting the article

Comment: @Aditya so i have tried this.props.articles.authorImage.fields in the component and it says it is undefined. i am giving getArticleSuccess >>article.items[0].fields<< so i don't have to mess around with needless code in my components. I use .fields again in the component as the authorImage has a fields property as well. I don't think its anything to do with .fields.

Comment: @R.Thompson I got it. misread article.items[0].fields in action corresponding to fields under authorImage